# Установка php-fpm CentOS

Tags: centos

При попытке сконфигурировать выдает сообщение об ошибке:

> Please specify full path to php source dir: --with-php=DIR

Сделал так, но не помогло:

```
$ ./configure --enable-fastcgi --enable-fpm --with-zlib --enable-pdo \
--with-pdo-mysql --with-mysql --with-config-file-path=/etc \
--enable-calendar --with-iconv --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-wddx \
--with-zlib --with-bz2 --with-gettext --with-xmlrpc --with-xml \
--enable-soap --enable-filepro --enable-bcmath --enable-trans-sid \
--enable-mbstring --enable-dbx --enable-dba --with-openssl --with-mhash \
--with-mcrypt --with-xsl --with-curl --with-pcre-regex --with-gd \
--enable-gd-native-ttf --with-ldap --enable-pdo --with-pdo-mysql \
--with-mysql --with-sqlite --with-pdo-sqlite --enable-sqlite-utf8 \
--with-pear --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-php=/usr/php
```

Какой путь указать?

Comment: Директория /usr/php существует

Comment: а что мешает установить пакет php-fpm из epel или remi дистрибутива ?
[как-то так](http://alecksey.com/install-nginx-php-fpm-on-centos)

Answer (score 1):

указать следует путь к **исходникам** именно той версии *php*, которая установлена на сервере.